# Tikz Fractal - Cantor Dust

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Is anyone able to help me draw the following fractal in Tikz?
[image]

Here we start of with the unit square, break it into 16 equal squares, and remove 12 of them - leaving 4 arranged as seen. The process is repeated on the remaining squares, and so on.

I am pretty sure I need to use something similar to [Nesting fractal tikz decorations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205595/nesting-fractal-tikz-decorations) but I am not good enough at TeX to compile the code myself.

Thank you in advance.

**My code so far:**

```
 \newcommand{\dust}[1]{
     \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{decorate\{}
     (0,0)--(1,1)
     \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{\}};

      SOMETHING IN HERE (DON'T KNOW)
 }

 \begin{tikzpicture}
     \path (0,0) pic {dust=5};
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us your code of what you have attempted.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please expand your code to a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). Reproducing will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Instead of decorations, you could use a normal tikzpicture as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228106/fractals-in-tikz?rq=1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a nice Lindenmayer system exercise.

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Cantor dust}{
    \symbol{S}{\pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\pgflsystemcurrentstep}{\pgflsystemcurrentstep}}}
    \symbol{U}{\pgftransformyshift{\pgflsystemcurrentstep}}
    \symbol{R}{\pgftransformxshift{\pgflsystemcurrentstep}}
    \rule{S -> [UUSURRS][RSRRUS]}
    \rule{U -> UUUU}
    \rule{R -> RRRR}
}
\tikz;
\tikz\fill[lindenmayer system={Cantor dust,axiom=S,step=320pt,order=1}]lindenmayer system;
\tikz\fill[lindenmayer system={Cantor dust,axiom=S,step= 80pt,order=2}]lindenmayer system;
\tikz\fill[lindenmayer system={Cantor dust,axiom=S,step= 20pt,order=3}]lindenmayer system;
\tikz\fill[lindenmayer system={Cantor dust,axiom=S,step=  5pt,order=4}]lindenmayer system;
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted :) thank you very much!

Comment: @Symbol I am trying to adapt this code to make the rules change the image to 5 squares of equal size instead of 4. I want 4 of the squares to be in the corners and 1 in the center. Could you help me please?

Comment: @PercyF2519 The rules should be `\rule{S -> S[U[US][RS]][RRSUUS]}\rule{U -> UUU}\rule{R -> RRR}`.

Comment: Thank you, I did manage to work out the code but mine isn't quite and neat as yours. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

I've just discovered this topic, which was related to another, more recent one. It can be considered as an application of recursive programming, for which [MetaPost](https://www.tug.org/metapost.html) is usually well suited. So here is a MetaPost solution, for whom it may interest.

```
def cantor_dust(expr x, y, d, n) = 
    if n > 0:
        cantor_dust(x+.25d, y, .25d, n-1);
        cantor_dust(x+.75d, y+.25d, .25d, n-1);
        cantor_dust(x+.5d, y+.75d, .25d, n-1);
        cantor_dust(x, y+.5d, .25d,  n-1);
    else: fill (x, y) -- (x+d, y) -- (x+d, y+d) -- (x, y+d) -- cycle; fi
enddef;
beginfig(1);
    for i = 0 upto 4:
        draw image(cantor_dust(0, 0, 4cm, i)) shifted (4.25cm*i, 0);
    endfor;
endfig;
end.
```

[image]