# Tikz Fractal - Menger Sponge

Tags: tikz-pgf

Ok so I am continuing my construction of fractals in Tikz - another one is here: [Tikz Fractal - Cantor Dust](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380025/tikz-fractal-cantor-dust). I was hoping someone would be able to help me create another, somewhat more complicated, fractal. It's called the Menger Sponge and is essentially a '3D' (although defining fractals as such is a little contradictory) Sierpinski Carpet. It looks like this:

[image]

Where you start with the unit cube, and recursively remove the centre 9th of each face all the way through the cube. A better, more precise description is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_sponge.

I'm thinking it should be possible with a 'lindenmayer system' but I have only a small amount of experience with those and I've never used it for 3D shapes.

After using Nancy-N's solution, I get this:

[image]

(notice the little lines around each smaller cube).

Comment: This is 3D with shadows so you better not bet on TikZ too much. I would try PSTricks or Asymptote for this.

Comment: @percusse Ok I have never used either of those, any suggestions?

Comment: Lines are probably just viewer artefacts.

Comment: @cfr Lines are artifacts somehow indeed, due to the fact that we are making the drawing by superimposing successively different small cubes (which are drawn as sets of color zones); and sometimes two zones which should be mathematically adjacent are drawn with a very small gap between them, at least in the redering of the viewer. A way to circumvent that is to change the code of level 0 so as to ask for a very slightly larger cube, so that small cubes will (slightly) overlap.

Comment: @JSharpee Now, Nancy's answer is complete. You should choose it so that I can remove mine... Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I do not know if this will make you happy, but yes, a kind of Lindenmayer system can work for your problem, using the fact that the cube is made of 20 copies of a 3-times-smaller itself, who themselves are made of a 3-times-smaller cube, and so on. Here is a way you can do it; I let you make the needed adaptations to get a better picture.

First generate a .tex file `level0.tex` with *no* `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}` or so, whose content just would be:

```
\fill[yellow] (1, 1, 1) -- (1, -1, 1) -- (-1, -1, 1) -- (-1, 1, 1) -- cycle;
\fill[cyan] (1, 1, 1) -- (1, 1, -1) -- (1, -1, -1) -- (1, -1, 1) -- cycle;
\fill[magenta] (1, 1, 1) -- (1, 1, -1) -- (-1, 1, -1) -- (-1, 1, 1) -- cycle;
```

Now you create a file `level1.tex` (again, no `\documentclass` or so) in which you use the content of `level0` twenty times as if you were putting several small cubes near each other. Beware that you have to draw the cubes in a correct order, so that a cube hiding another one will only be drawn *after* it. Your file `level1.tex` would be the following:

```
\begin{scope}[scale=.3333333333]
\begin{scope}[shift={(-2, -2, -2)}]
\input{level0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(0, -2, -2)}]
\input{level0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(2, -2, -2)}]
\input{level0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(-2, 0, -2)}]
\input{level0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(2, 0, -2)}]
\input{level0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(-2, 2, -2)}]
\input{level0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(0, 2, -2)}]
\input{level0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(2, 2, -2)}]
\input{level0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(-2, -2, 0)}]
\input{level0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(2, -2, 0)}]
\input{level0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(-2, 2, 0)}]
\input{level0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(2, 2, 0)}]
\input{level0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(-2, -2, 2)}]
\input{level0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(0, -2, 2)}]
\input{level0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(2, -2, 2)}]
\input{level0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(-2, 0, 2)}]
\input{level0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(2, 0, 2)}]
\input{level0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(-2, 2, 2)}]
\input{level0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(0, 2, 2)}]
\input{level0}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(2, 2, 2)}]
\input{level0}
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
```

Next you create a file `level2.tex` which is the same as `level1.tex`, except that `\input{level0}` is replaced by `\input{level1}`. And finally your final drawing (inside a real `.tex` source file with `\documentclass` and so on) will be

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\input{level2}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Below is the rendering I get. Of course you can go up to level 3, 4 or so, at least theoretically, but do not forget that the amount of computation and memory used will be multiplied by a factor 20 at each further level!

[image: Menger sponge, level 2]

Kind regards,
/Nancy-N

---

*EDIT:* Paul Gaborit has quite nicely improved my solution by coding a command `\mengersponge` taking one argument, so that you do not have to create one file per level. Here is his code (where he also chose more relevant colours ;-)):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\newcommand\mengersponge[1]{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\level{int(#1 - 1)}
  \ifnum \level = 0 \relax
  \filldraw[gray!50!black,line width=0] (1, 1, 1) -- (1, 1, -1) -- (1, -1, -1) -- (1, -1, 1) -- cycle;
  \filldraw[gray,line width=0] (1, 1, 1) -- (1, 1, -1) -- (-1, 1, -1) -- (-1, 1, 1) -- cycle;
  \filldraw[gray!50,line width=0] (1, 1, 1) -- (1, -1, 1) -- (-1, -1, 1) -- (-1, 1, 1) -- cycle;
  \else
  \begin{scope}[scale=.3333333333]
    \begin{scope}[shift={(-2, -2, -2)}]
      \mengersponge{\level}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0, -2, -2)}]
      \mengersponge{\level}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(2, -2, -2)}]
      \mengersponge{\level}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(-2, 0, -2)}]
      \mengersponge{\level}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(2, 0, -2)}]
      \mengersponge{\level}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(-2, 2, -2)}]
      \mengersponge{\level}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0, 2, -2)}]
      \mengersponge{\level}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(2, 2, -2)}]
      \mengersponge{\level}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(-2, -2, 0)}]
      \mengersponge{\level}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(2, -2, 0)}]
      \mengersponge{\level}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(-2, 2, 0)}]
      \mengersponge{\level}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(2, 2, 0)}]
      \mengersponge{\level}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(-2, -2, 2)}]
      \mengersponge{\level}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0, -2, 2)}]
      \mengersponge{\level}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(2, -2, 2)}]
      \mengersponge{\level}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(-2, 0, 2)}]
      \mengersponge{\level}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(2, 0, 2)}]
      \mengersponge{\level}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(-2, 2, 2)}]
      \mengersponge{\level}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0, 2, 2)}]
      \mengersponge{\level}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(2, 2, 2)}]
      \mengersponge{\level}
    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \mengersponge{4}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With `pdflatex`, Paul Gaborit could only perform the computations up to level 3 (corresponding to `\mengersponge{4}` in his code), which took 40 seconds to compilate; but with `lualatex` he could compile level 4 (corresponding to `\mengersponge{5}`). Below are his pictures :-)

For level 3:

[image: Menger sponge, level 3]

For level 4:

[image: Menger sponge, level 4]

Regards,
/Nancy-N

Comment: I might go for milder colors... but I'll give it a go, thank you.

Comment: It is messy as hell but it does work. Thank you. The only issue is that there are little lines around all of the cubes (see update).

Comment: Mathematically speaking, I would not say that it is messy actually; but it is a huge waste of cumputing power undoubtedly ;-) As regards the issue of small lines, see my answer to cfr's comment under your main post.

Comment: @JSharpee Notice that you are not forced to keep this orientation of the cube, of course: you can ask TikZ to choose the representation of the basic vectors (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0) and (0, 0, 1) the way you want ;-)

Comment: @Nancy-N The compilation of `\mengersponge{4}` takes 40 seconds. The compilation of `\mengersponge{5}` takes a much longer time! ;-)