# How to draw a cube as the following?

Tags: pstricks, pst-solides3d

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
\psset{viewpoint=120 50 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=50}
\pstVerb{/Colors [(red)(yellow)(orange)(green)(blue)] def }
\def\figure#1#2{%
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\psframe[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!50](-3,-3)(3,3)
    \psSolid[action=draw**,a=8,object=cube,fillcolor=green!30,ngrid=3,%
    rm=4 40 13 31 53 22,hollow,incolor=pink!50,Rot#2=-#1\space]%
    \end{pspicture}
}
    \multido{\iA=0+5}{72}{\figure{\iA}{X}}
\end{document}
```

[image]
It is hollowed inside the cube.

So, how to get the similar output to the following image?

[image]

%% From Herbert's comment

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-4.5,-3.5)(6,6)
\psset{Decran=60,viewpoint=80 35 15 rtp2xyz,a=1,lightsrc=80 30 20,}
%   \psSolid[object=grille,base=0 7 0 7,fillcolor=gray!40]%%
%   \psSolid[object=grille,base=0 7 0 7,RotY=90,fillcolor=gray!30](0,0,7)%
%   \psSolid[object=grille,base=0 7 0 7,RotX=-90,fillcolor=gray!20](0,0,7)%
\def\figure#1#2#3{\psSolid[object=cube,fcol=1 (green) 2 (blue) 3 (red) 4 (pink) 5 (orange) 6 (cyan)](#1,#2,#3)}
    \foreach \i in {0.5,1.5,2.5}{\figure{0.5}{\i}{0.5}}
    \foreach \i in {1.5,2.5}{\figure{\i}{.5}{0.5}}
    \figure{1.5}{2.5}{0.5}
    \foreach \i in {1.5,2.5}{\figure{2.5}{\i}{0.5}}
    \foreach \i in {1.5,2.5}{\figure{.5}{.5}{\i}}
    \figure{2.5}{.5}{1.5}
    \figure{.5}{1.5}{2.5}
    \foreach \i in {1.5,2.5}{\figure{\i}{.5}{2.5}}
    \figure{2.5}{1.5}{2.5}
    \foreach \i in {1.5,2.5}{\figure{.5}{2.5}{\i}}
    \figure{1.5}{2.5}{2.5}
    \foreach \i in {1.5,2.5}{\figure{2.5}{2.5}{\i}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But with viewpoint=80 135 15 rtp2xyz , I get the following:

[image]

Comment: I think that there are two aspects. The first one, how to draw a cube with holes, has been discussed e.g. in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383419/121799. And then your screen shot has a perspective view. Unless you want to use `asymptote` you might be interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447120/121799 if you insist on the perspective view. If not, please add the information that you are not to your question. (+1)

Comment: The only difference is that you have to place 7*49-7*35-6*5 simple squares. This can be done by using the coordinates `\psSolid[object=cube,..](x,y,z)`.  That's all

Comment: You have to use `solidmemory, action=none,name=cubeXXX` and then an object `fusion`. See documentation for a lot of examples. Without the `object=fusion` you cannot have hidden surfaces.

Comment: see extended answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you do not want the inside also with cubes, it is simple:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
\psset{viewpoint=120 60 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=50}
\pstVerb{/Colors [(red)(yellow)(orange)(green)(blue)] def }
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\psSolid[action=draw**,a=8,object=cube,fillcolor=green!30,ngrid=7,%
    rm=  8  12  24  36  40 
        57  61  73  85  89
       106 110 122 134 138
       155 159 171 183 187
       208 212 220 228 232
       269 273 281 289 293,
        hollow,incolor=blue!30]%
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And as single cubes:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\def\Figure#1#2#3#4{%
    \psSolid[object=cube,name=c#4,ngrid=1,a=1,
             action=none,fcol=1 (green) 2 (blue) 3 (red) 4 (pink) 5 (orange) 6 (cyan)](#1,#2,#3)}

\begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}(-4.5,-3.5)(6,6)
    \psset{Decran=60,viewpoint=80 10 15 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=viewpoint,solidmemory}
    \foreach \i/\j in {0.5/1,1.5/2,2.5/3}{\Figure{0.5}{\i}{0.5}{\j}}
    \foreach \i/\j in {1.5/4,2.5/5}{\Figure{\i}{.5}{0.5}{\j}}
    \Figure{1.5}{2.5}{0.5}{6}
    \foreach \i/\j in {1.5/7,2.5/8}{\Figure{2.5}{\i}{0.5}{\j}}
    \foreach \i/\j in {1.5/9,2.5/10}{\Figure{.5}{.5}{\i}{\j}}
    \Figure{2.5}{.5}{1.5}{11}
    \Figure{.5}{1.5}{2.5}{12}
    \foreach \i/\j in {1.5/13,2.5/14}{\Figure{\i}{.5}{2.5}{\j}}
    \Figure{2.5}{1.5}{2.5}{15}
    \foreach \i/\j in {1.5/16,2.5/17}{\Figure{.5}{2.5}{\i}{\j}}
    \Figure{1.5}{2.5}{2.5}{18}
    \foreach \i/\j in {1.5/19,2.5/20}{\Figure{2.5}{2.5}{\i}{\j}}
    \psSolid[object=fusion,
             base=c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10 c11 c12 c13 c14 c15 c16 c17 c18 c19 c20]
    \composeSolid
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For a lot of cubes you can simplify the fusion object:

```
\def\cubes{}
\multido{\iA=1+1}{20}{\xdef\cubes{\cubes\space c\iA}}
\begin{pspicture} ....
    ....    
    \psSolid[object=fusion, base=\cubes]
    ....
```

and here is a way how you can build the complete cube:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\newcounter{fig}
\def\Figure#1#2#3{%
    \stepcounter{fig}%
    \psSolid[object=cube,name=c\thefig,ngrid=1,a=1,
             action=none,fcol=1 (green) 2 (blue) 3 (red) 4 (pink) 5 (orange) 6 (cyan)](#1,#2,#3)}

\begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}(-5,-3.5)(4,6)
    \psset{Decran=60,viewpoint=80 60 15 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=viewpoint,solidmemory}
    \multido{\iA=0+1}{7}{%
      \multido{\iB=0+1}{7}{%
         \multido{\iC=0+1}{7}{%
           \Figure{\iB}{\iA}{\iC}%
    }}}%
    \psSolid[object=fusion, base=
    % 1
       c1   c2   c3   c4   c5   c6   c7
       c8        c10  c11  c12       c14
       c15  c16  c17  c18  c19  c20  c21
       c22  c23  c24       c26  c27  c28
       c29  c30  c31  c32  c33  c34  c35
       c36       c38  c39  c40       c42
       c43  c44  c45  c46  c47  c48  c49
    % 2
       c50       c52  c53  c54       c56
    %      
       c64       c66  c67  c68       c70
       c71       c73       c75       c77
       c78       c80  c81  c82       c84
    %      
       c92       c94  c95  c96       c98
     % 3 ...
      ]
    \composeSolid
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and the complete image:

[image]

Comment: see edited answer for simplifying the list of cubes

Comment: With your animation, you change _viewpoint_ or _Rot?=..._ ?

Comment: ' viewpoint=80 \iD\space 10 rtp2xyz'

Comment: "And as single cubes..." ... When will you start giving credit to others from whom you get the ideas?

Answer (score 14):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{plane/.style n args={3}{insert path={%
#1 -- ++ #2 -- ++ #3 -- ++ ($-1*#2$) -- cycle}},
unit xy plane/.style={plane={#1}{(1,0,0)}{(0,1,0)}},
unit xz plane/.style={plane={#1}{(1,0,0)}{(0,0,1)}},
unit yz plane/.style={plane={#1}{(0,1,0)}{(0,0,1)}},
get projections/.style={insert path={%
let \p1=(1,0,0),\p2=(0,1,0)  in 
[/utils/exec={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xproj}{sign(\x1)}\xdef\xproj{\xproj}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\yproj}{sign(\x2)}\xdef\yproj{\yproj}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\zproj}{sign(cos(\tdplotmaintheta))}\xdef\zproj{\zproj}}]}},
pics/unit cube/.style={code={
\path[get projections];
\draw (0,0,0) -- (1,1,1);
\ifnum\zproj=-1
 \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/xy face,unit xy plane={(0,0,0)}]; 
\fi
\ifnum\yproj=1
 \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/yz face,unit yz plane={(1,0,0)}]; 
\else
 \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/yz face,unit yz plane={(0,0,0)}]; 
\fi
\ifnum\xproj=1
 \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/xz face,unit xz plane={(0,0,0)}]; 
\else
 \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/xz face,unit xz plane={(0,1,0)}]; 
\fi
\ifnum\zproj>-1
 \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/xy face,unit xy plane={(0,0,1)}]; 
\fi
}},
3d cube/.cd,
xy face/.style={fill=orange},
xz face/.style={fill=blue},
yz face/.style={fill=red},
every face/.style={draw,very thick}
}
\begin{document}
\foreach \Angle in {5,15,...,355} 
{\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{\Angle} % the first argument cannot be larger than 90
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NumCubes}{7}
 \path[use as bounding box] (-\NumCubes/2-3,-\NumCubes/2-2) 
 rectangle (\NumCubes/2+3,\NumCubes/2+4);
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NextToLast}{\NumCubes-1}
  \path[get projections];
  \ifnum\yproj=1
   \def\LstX{1,...,\NumCubes}
  \else 
   \def\LstX{\NumCubes,\NextToLast,...,1}
  \fi
  \ifnum\xproj=-1
   \def\LstY{1,...,\NumCubes}
  \else 
   \def\LstY{\NumCubes,\NextToLast,...,1}
  \fi
  \ifnum\zproj=1
   \def\LstZ{1,...,\NumCubes}
  \else 
   \def\LstZ{\NumCubes,\NextToLast,...,1}
  \fi
  \foreach \X in \LstX
  {\foreach \Y in \LstY
   {\foreach \Z in \LstZ
    {\xdef\itest{1}
     \ifodd\X
     \else
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\jtest}{mod(\X+\Y,4)}
       \ifnum\jtest=0
        \xdef\itest{0}
       \fi
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\jtest}{mod(\X+\Z,4)}
       \ifnum\jtest=0
        \xdef\itest{0}
       \fi
     \fi
     \ifodd\Y
     \else
       \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\jtest}{mod(\Y+\Z,4)}
       \ifnum\jtest=0
        \xdef\itest{0}
       \fi
     \fi
     \ifnum\itest=1
     \path (\X-\NumCubes/2-1/2,\Y-\NumCubes/2-1/2,\Z-\NumCubes/2-1/2) pic{unit cube};
     \fi}}
  }
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]