# Incomplete cube

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw an incomplete cube, as in the following figure.

[image]

But, I can only draw a complete cube, see below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[on grid][scale=1.4]
  \shade[yslant=-0.5,right color=white, left color=white]
    (0,0) rectangle +(3,3);
  \draw[yslant=-0.5] (0,0) grid (3,3);
  \shade[yslant=0.5,right color=white,left color=white]
    (3,-3) rectangle +(3,3);
  \draw[yslant=0.5] (3,-3) grid (6,0);
  \shade[yslant=0.5,xslant=-1,bottom color=white,
    top color=white] (6,3) rectangle +(-3,-3);
  \draw[yslant=0.5,xslant=-1] (3,0) grid (6,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would like to argue that one should use orthographic projections and write it in such a way that one can change the view angle. There are already many posts on this, perhaps most impressingly [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444815/121799). The idea to use `pic`s for the unit cubes to draw 3d cubes with some little cubes missing is also not new, it has been used [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479023/121799), where the cubes are rotatable in 3d. I just recycled the code to get

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{plane/.style n args={3}{insert path={%
#1 -- ++ #2 -- ++ #3 -- ++ ($-1*#2$) -- cycle}},
unit xy plane/.style={plane={#1}{(1,0,0)}{(0,1,0)}},
unit xz plane/.style={plane={#1}{(1,0,0)}{(0,0,1)}},
unit yz plane/.style={plane={#1}{(0,1,0)}{(0,0,1)}},
get projections/.style={insert path={%
let \p1=(1,0,0),\p2=(0,1,0)  in 
[/utils/exec={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xproj}{sign(\x1)}\xdef\xproj{\xproj}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\yproj}{sign(\x2)}\xdef\yproj{\yproj}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\zproj}{sign(cos(\tdplotmaintheta))}\xdef\zproj{\zproj}}]}},
pics/unit cube/.style={code={
\path[get projections];
\draw (0,0,0) -- (1,1,1);
\ifnum\zproj=-1
 \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/xy face,unit xy plane={(0,0,0)}]; 
\fi
\ifnum\yproj=1
 \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/yz face,unit yz plane={(1,0,0)}]; 
\else
 \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/yz face,unit yz plane={(0,0,0)}]; 
\fi
\ifnum\xproj=1
 \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/xz face,unit xz plane={(0,0,0)}]; 
\else
 \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/xz face,unit xz plane={(0,1,0)}]; 
\fi
\ifnum\zproj>-1
 \path[3d cube/every face,3d cube/xy face,unit xy plane={(0,0,1)}]; 
\fi
}},
3d cube/.cd,
xy face/.style={fill=gray!20},
xz face/.style={fill=gray!50},
yz face/.style={fill=gray!90},
every face/.style={draw,very thick}
}
\begin{document}
\foreach \Angle in {5,15,...,355} 
{\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{\Angle} % the first argument cannot be larger than 90
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NumCubes}{7}
 \path[use as bounding box] (-\NumCubes/2-3,-\NumCubes/2-2) 
 rectangle (\NumCubes/2+3,\NumCubes/2+4);
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NextToLast}{\NumCubes-1}
  \path[get projections];
  \ifnum\yproj=1
   \def\LstX{1,2,3}
  \else 
   \def\LstX{3,2,1}
  \fi
  \ifnum\xproj=-1
   \def\LstY{1,2,3}
  \else 
   \def\LstY{3,2,1}
  \fi
  \foreach \X in \LstX
  {\foreach \Y in \LstY
   {\ifnum\Y=3
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Zmax}{5-max(\X,2)}
   \else
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Zmax}{4-\X}
   \fi
   \foreach \Z in {1,...,\Zmax}
    {\path (\X-2,\Y-2,\Z-1) pic{unit cube};}}
  }
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "I would like to argue that one should use orthographic projections".  Spoken like a true engineer!  +1

Answer (score 18):

You can define a single cube as `pic` and place it where you want (starting from bottom back to top front).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  cube/.pic={
    \draw[fill=black!20] (0,1,0) -- (0,1,1) -- (1,1,1) -- (1,1,0);
    \draw[fill=black!50] (1,0,0) -- (1,0,1) -- (1,1,1) -- (1,1,0);
    \draw[fill=white] (0,0,0) rectangle (1,1,0);
  }
}
\begin{document}
  \tikz[z={(.4,.3)}]\path\pgfextra{\def~{pic{cube}}} % <--- to make the code shorter
      (2,0,2)~(2,0,1)~(0,0,0)~(1,0,0)~(2,0,0)~
      (2,1,2)~(1,1,1)~(0,1,0)~(1,1,0)~
      (0,2,2)~(1,2,2)~(0,2,1)~(0,2,0)~;
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ...better to use the redefined `~` version inside a group, even if it's just to shorten your code. As in, `\begingroup \def~{pic{code}} \begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: @Werner Agree, thanks. Done.

Comment: The `\pgfextra` and `{...}` only to avoid `{` and `}`? `  \tikz[z={(.4,.3)}]{\def~{pic{cube}}
     \path (2,0,2)~(2,0,1)~(0,0,0)~(1,0,0)~(2,0,0)~
      (2,1,2)~(1,1,1)~(0,1,0)~(1,1,0)~
      (0,2,2)~(1,2,2)~(0,2,1)~(0,2,0)~;}`

Comment: @marmot I never avoid shorter code in general ;) But here, as redefining `~` is not a good practice, I decided to follow the comment of @Werner and to make its definition as local as possible : so local to the path is better to local for the entire tikz.

Comment: If that's your aim:`\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  cube/.pic={
    \draw[fill=black!20] (0,1,0) -- (0,1,1) -- (1,1,1) -- (1,1,0);
    \draw[fill=black!50] (1,0,0) -- (1,0,1) -- (1,1,1) -- (1,1,0);
    \draw[fill=white] (0,0,0) rectangle (1,1,0);
  },icube/.style={insert path={#1 pic{cube}}}
}
\begin{document}
  \tikz[z={(.4,.3)}]\path[icube/.list={(2,0,2),(2,0,1),(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(2,0,0),
      (2,1,2),(1,1,1),(0,1,0),(1,1,0),
      (0,2,2),(1,2,2),(0,2,1),(0,2,0)}];
\end{document}`

Answer (score 14):

Just for fun: everything is in 2D

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1) (1,1) rectangle (2,2) (0,1) rectangle (1,2) (0,2) rectangle (1,3) (1,0) rectangle (2,1) (2,0) rectangle (3,1);
\draw (3.6,1.6)--(3.6,.6)--(3,0)--(3,1)--cycle--(3.6,2.6)--(2.6,2.6)--(2.6,3.6)--(.6,3.6)--(0,3);
\draw (2,1)--(2.4,1.4) (2,2)--(2.6,2.6) (1,2)--(1.4,2.4) (1,3)--(1.6,3.6) (2.4,3.4)--(2.6,3.6) (3.4,2.4)--(3.6,2.6); 
\draw (2.4,1.4) rectangle (3.4,2.4) (1.4,2.4) rectangle (2.4,3.4);
\draw (.4,3.4)--(1.4,3.4) (3.4,1.4)--(3.4,.4) (.2,3.2)--(1.2,3.2)--(1.2,2.2)--(2.2,2.2)--(2.2,1.2)--(3.2,1.2)--(3.2,.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With colors

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[black!70] (3,0)--(3.6,.6)--(3.6,2.6)--(3.4,2.4)--(3.4,1.4)--(3,1)--cycle (2.4,2.4)--(2.6,2.6)--(2.6,3.6)--(2.4,3.4)--(2.4,1.4)--(2,1)--(2,2)--cycle (1,2)--(1.4,2.4)--(1.4,3.4)--(1,3)--cycle;
\fill[black!30] (0,3)--(.6,3.6)-_(2.6,3.6)--(2.4,3.4)--(1.4,3.4)--(1,3)--cycle (2.4,2.4)--(2.6,2.6)--(3.6,2.6)--(3.4,2.4)--(1.4,2.4)--(1,2)--(2,2)--cycle (2,1)--(2.4,1.4)--(3.4,1.4)--(3,1)--cycle;
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1) (1,1) rectangle (2,2) (0,1) rectangle (1,2) (0,2) rectangle (1,3) (1,0) rectangle (2,1) (2,0) rectangle (3,1);
\draw (3.6,1.6)--(3.6,.6)--(3,0)--(3,1)--cycle--(3.6,2.6)--(2.6,2.6)--(2.6,3.6)--(.6,3.6)--(0,3);
\draw (2,1)--(2.4,1.4) (2,2)--(2.6,2.6) (1,2)--(1.4,2.4) (1,3)--(1.6,3.6) (2.4,3.4)--(2.6,3.6) (3.4,2.4)--(3.6,2.6); 
\draw (2.4,1.4) rectangle (3.4,2.4) (1.4,2.4) rectangle (2.4,3.4);
\draw (.4,3.4)--(1.4,3.4) (3.4,1.4)--(3.4,.4) (.2,3.2)--(1.2,3.2)--(1.2,2.2)--(2.2,2.2)--(2.2,1.2)--(3.2,1.2)--(3.2,.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]