# What is the correct way to typeset a vector when there is subscript or superscript?

Tags: arrows, subscripts, superscripts, vector

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[\vec{v}_{12345}^{12345678}\]

\[\overrightarrow{P_{12345}P_{12345}^{12345678}}\]

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

As you can see, `\vec` is designed to typeset a vector with an arrow above the argument.

However, when we do not have a unary symbol to represent a vector (e.g. the difference between the coordinates of two points) then we can use `\overrightarrow`. But this notation has two problems:

1. When we are working with long chain of numbers `\overrightarrow` collides with it, as shown in the example.
2. And I think the most important: it is not consistent with `\vec`. Why? Because `\vec` stops the arrow before the subscript/superscript, but `\overrightarrow` continues the arrow to the end regardless of the existence or not of subscript/superscript.

Remember that we are writing vectors, no matter the length of the text that represents the vector.

### What I want

With your huge help, I would like to write the following:

[image: Example of what I want]

[image: Example 2 of what I want]

[image: Example 3 of what I want]

Thanks!!

Comment: You can do that e.g. with `\[\overrightarrow{P_{12345}P}\!_{12345}^{\,12345678}\]` but I promise you that in a few years you will find this notation awkward.

Comment: @marmot I am not a mathematician but a student of ingeering, so the conventions are our thing. :P

Comment: it's best to avoid the over-arrow notation, especially you need it for anything more than _x_

Comment: Then see [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482561/incomplete-cube/482592#comment1219941_482592) ... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems a really confusing (and ugly) convention, but..

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\sbox0{$P$}
\[\overrightarrow{\strut P_{12345}\kern\wd0}\kern-\wd0P_{12345}^{12345678}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! The original `\overrightarrow` stops the arrow just after the last `P`, and your solution stops it at the middle. How can we stop the arrow a little more to the right?

Comment: @manooooh middle? it goes to the right edge (bar the sidebearing on the arrowhead) but use `\kern1.1\wd0}\kern-1.1\wd0` if you prefer (or any other factor)

Comment: @manooooh Generally I use the notation for a vector of `\overline` or `\widebar` or `esvect` package.